# Android - Convert other app class name to view in service class

Tags: android, class, android-activity

I have class name of the other app and in my app I have a service class where I need to initialize a view which is the other app activity view. How can I convert that string class name to activity and that activity to view ? I am trying to access other app activity so class loader doesn't work.

Comment: This may be the most confusingly worded question ever. Please slow down and really think through what you are trying to do. Use examples and show some code samples. Describe what you tried and what error messages were etc.

Comment: Is there a way to control other app from my app. Other app runs on adobe air framework and mine is the native android app. I want to resume, pause, stop the adobe air app from my app service class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to comprehend exactly what you are asking bit it seems you want to know how to communicate between apps.

There are mechanisms for apps to talk/control each other but you can't simply use the compiled code in another app directly.  You have to communicate via either:

1. [Intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)
2. [Exported services via AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)
3. [Broadcast Receivers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) (to get notifications/messages between apps).
4. [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) that are exported or if apps are signed with the same key (to share data)
5. [Shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) assuming both apps are signed with the same keys. (to share data)
6. Sockets - You can implement IPC with tcp sockets that communicate on the localhost via tcp. (didn't find any great examples online but my company has built an app that does this).